# can i plug 2.5A cord to 120W 6.32 19V AC adapter

Tags: ac, charger, adapter

I bought An asus charger for my laptop 120W 6.32 19V AC adapter, it cam with out AC plug, i got a plug from a regular charger with 2.5A ~250V.

will this affect the power going to the AC adapter since the plug says it's 2.5A and the AC supports up to 6.32A ?

Noting that when i but the PC into stress charger go's down and up

Comment: if the plug fits and the cable meets the relavant standards it should be good.  2.5A is the "mickey-mouse" looking connector  I think.  my 135W laptop charger uses that cable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Power math: 
You have 6.32A by 19V  >>>   6.32A*19V = 120W

You need to supply 120W and with 2.5A by 250V you can provide around 2.5*250V = 625W  (That is simplyfied for AC Power calculation). So it is ok to use it.